Can "nullptr" fully replace "NULL" in C23?
Is NULL fully interchangeable with nullptr in C23? Are they used in separate scenarios?
I'm coding a game, and there are moments where I've used NULL and others where I've used nullptr. I initially started with a C99 approach, but after seeing all the new features of C23, I decided to switch. However, some parts of my code still use the old NULL, and I've been wondering if there might be any issues replacing it with the new nullptr to avoid memory leaks or other problems.
I asked chatgpt about it but it still keeps thinking nullptr is only C++ stuff.

C23, which first introduced nullptr to the C language, was officially published less than two months ago. Therefore, it is not surprising if ChatGPT is not yet aware of this change and associates it only with C++.

There are edge cases where NULL can't be replaced with nullptr, but they are mostly misuses of NULL to begin with. One of the reasons for nullptr's existence is to reduce the potential ways to misuse NULL.

nullptr is for when you definitely want the value to be a pointer. Historically, some systems have defined NULL as 0 and then people have used it as a non-pointer value as well. The "issues" you will find is that such code will stop working when you replace it with nullptr.

The technical/theoretical answer to your question is no, there are situations where changing NULL to nullptr will change the behavior of the code. The practical answer is yes, change all your uses of NULL to nullptr. If you used NULL as it was intended, the code will be fine with nullptr.

If you ask this question and you primary consult at chatgpt, you are likely a beginner. In such circumstances, using nullptr is safe and even preferable.

Doesn't it depend on what NULL is defined as?  I've seen implementations where it is something else other than 0 and the coders who've assumed zero have fallen foul of this.

@cup: Yes, that is correct. NULL can be defined as either 0 or ((void*)0). It depends on the implementation which of these definitions is used. The expression nullptr on the other hand is a value of type nullptr_t.

printf("%p\n", nullptr); is OK.  printf("%p\n", NULL); is not.

@chux: I believe that printf("%p\n", nullptr); will strictly speaking also invoke undefined behavior, because the argument is of type nullptr_t and §7.23.6.1 ¶8 of the ISO C23 standard states the following for %p: "The argument shall be a pointer to void or a pointer to a character type."

@AndreasWenzel Hmmm, IMO if the net result is UB, then that is a defect in C23.

@chux: If it's a defect, it's a defect in the way standard C (of any vintage) treats arguments in the ... part of the argument list of a variadic function.  The defect exists in C90, C99, C11 and C17 as well as C23.  It's not a defect in nullptr per se.
